# Lightning-datatable sorting throws "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setAttribute')" error

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have a lightning-datatable that is defined so it can be sorted by a few different columns. This is the code:

```
<lightning-datatable
        lwc:if={data}
        key-field="id"
        data={data}
        columns={columns}
        onrowaction={handleRowAction}
        onsort={handleOnSort}
        sorted-by={sortBy}
        sorted-direction={sortDirection}
        column-widths-mode="auto"
        resize-column-disabled
        hide-checkbox-column>
</lightning-datatable>
```

This is the definition of the columns:

```
const COLUMNS = [
{label: 'Cultivo', fieldName: 'cultivo', fixedWidth: 150},
{label: 'Nro Comprobante', fieldName: 'numero'},
{label: 'Marca', fieldName: 'obtentor'},
{label: 'Comercio', fieldName: 'comercio'},
{label: 'Fecha Emisión', fieldName: 'fecha', type: 'date', sortable: true},
{label: 'Fecha Vencimiento', fieldName: 'fechaVencimiento', type: 'date', sortable: true},
{label: 'Importe USD', fieldName: 'total', type: 'currency', sortable: true},
{label: 'Saldo USD', fieldName: 'saldo', type: 'currency', sortable: true},
{label: 'Saldo ARS', fieldName: 'saldoArs', type: 'currency', sortable: true},
{type: 'button-icon', typeAttributes: {alternativeText: 'Ver Factura', iconName: 'utility:file', name: 'Ver', title: 'Ver'}},
{type: 'button', typeAttributes: {label: 'Pagar', name: 'Pagar', title: 'Pagar', disabled: {fieldName: 'disablePagar'}}},
{type: 'button', typeAttributes: {label: 'Informar Pago', name: 'Informar Pago', title: 'Informar Pago', disabled: {fieldName: 'disableInfPago'}}}
];
```

And the JS methods:

```
handleOnSort(event){
    this.sortBy = event.detail.fieldName;
    this.sortDirection = event.detail.sortDirection;
    console.log(this.sortBy, this.sortDirection);
    this.sortData();
}

sortData() {
    const parseData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));
    // Return the value stored in the field
    const keyValue = (a) => {
        return a[this.sortBy];
    };
    // cheking reverse direction
    const isReverse = this.sortDirection === 'asc' ? 1: -1;
    // sorting data
    parseData.sort((x, y) => {
        x = keyValue(x) ? keyValue(x) : ''; // handling null values
        y = keyValue(y) ? keyValue(y) : '';
        // sorting values based on direction
        return isReverse * ((x > y) - (y > x));
    });

    this.data = parseData;
}
```

Both sortBy and sortDirection properties are tracked and have initial values. The data renderds correctly at first, I can click one of the sortable columns and it works but when I try to sort it again, it throws the following error:

[image]

I can't find what is wrong with my code.. is it a problem with the data itself? I don't get it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: please enable debug mode for the user to get which line is throwing this exception and in this browser log, you will be able to see not obfuscated code

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskyi hey! I enabled LWC debug mode for the user, I just edited the post with the not obfuscated code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`lwc:if`/`lwc:elseif`/`lwc:else` does not work correctly when used on non-`<template>` tags. Change your code as follows:

```
<template lwc:if={data}>
    <lightning-datatable
        key-field="id"
        data={data}
        columns={columns}
        onrowaction={handleRowAction}
        onsort={handleOnSort}
        sorted-by={sortBy}
        sorted-direction={sortDirection}
        column-widths-mode="auto"
        resize-column-disabled
        hide-checkbox-column>
    </lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-conditional.html) does warn you of this limitation:

> To render HTML conditionally, add the `lwc:if|elseif={property}` and `lwc:else` directive to a nested `<template>` tag that encloses the conditional content.

This is a change from `if:true` and `if:false` directives, which worked on any element.

Comment: I just changed every lwc:if I have to template tags and the error still occurs. Thank you for the input though!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a duplicate key field error in the datatable that wasn't showing in the console because I didn't have LWC debug mode enabled for that user. I changed the field used as key-field and the sorting works perfectly. Thank you @sfdcfox anyway for the information about lwc:if I'll have that in mind.